# Sketch: I have the vector mode by default, how can I change it back?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

I am using Sketch, its been a few days the vector option is in default.
For example:

- I create a shape, nothing happens when I hover on it
- I can only drag it
- double click vector mode, if I try to enlarge it, only one side moves.

I can't explain what happened. How do I get out of the vector mode?

Answer (score 1):

Hit escape to exit vector editing mode.